# Storing @include() in a variable?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Is it possible to store the output of `@include('view.name')` into a variable?

Something like this:

```
$var = @include('view.name')
{{$var}}
```

The reason I want to do that I want to pass `@include('view.name')` into `Blade::directive()`

For example:

```
@blocksection([
        'Title',
        '<p>Descrption</p>,
         @include('view.name'),
])
// HTML 
@endblocksection
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is possible, but I'd rather do it in the following way (a cleaner approach I think):

1. In the corresponding controller, render the view manually and store it in some variable
   `$var = view('view.name')->render()`
2. Pass the variable to the target template
   `return view('your template', ['var' => $var])`
3. Just use it now :D

Comment: You almost there, but I think passing `$var` into `@blocksection([$var])` would not work. `Blade::directive` will treat `$var` as string

Comment: it's my fault because I didn't read the entire question and rushed to the keyboard :D. anyway give it a try and give me feedback (I guess it would work :D)